# Bench with two supports - Rigid Body Dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rigid-body-dynamics

A bench in a park is a thick plank of mass $M$ and length $L$, placed symmetrically on two supports that are $L/2$ apart. A student of mass $m$ sits on the edge of the bench. Determine the force the bench exerts on each of the supports.

If this were a single support I wouldn't have a problem, but I don't quite know how to use the dynamics of a rigid body here with two supports. All I know is that I need to consider two forces on the bench - the student's weight force applied to, say, the right end of the bench ($Q_s$) and the weight force of the bench itself applied to the centre of mass ($Q_b$).

Anyone have an idea how to determine these exerted forces? Apologies if the drawing seems vaguely symmetrical.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a rigid body to remain in equilibrium, [the net force and net torque on it must be zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics), i.e.
$$\sum_i \vec F_i=0$$
$$\sum_i \vec r_i\times\vec F_i=0$$
where $\vec r_i$ is the position at which force $\vec F_i$ is applied (the choice of origin doesn't matter), and $\times$ denotes the cross product.

In your example, all forces are vertical ($\vec F_i = F_i \hat y$) and they are applied at points along the plank ($\vec r_i = x_i \hat x$), so the equations reduce to
$$\sum_i F_i=0$$
$$\sum_i x_i F_i=0.$$

Comment: Yeah, I know all of that, I just don't know how to practically apply that knowledge in this case.

Comment: @PK96 Make a list of all the forces $F_i$ and the locations $x_i$ where they are applied. Write down the above equations. Solve these equations for the unknown $F_i$.

Comment: Since the choice of the origin does not matter, can I calculate the torques with respect to the point where the second support meets the bench for the remaining forces (weight of the student, weight of the bench and force acting on the first support) and sum these torques to 0? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @PK96 That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

> If this were a single support I wouldn't have a problem, but I don't
> quite know how to use the dynamics of a rigid body here with two
> supports.

Hint: This only becomes a dynamics problem if the mass of the student is greater than the mass of the plank, and the plank is simply resting on and not pinned to the left support.  Then you will have a net clockwise torque about the right support resulting in angular acceleration with the downward force on the right support equal to $mg-Mg$. Otherwise, you need to treat the problem as a statics problem using $\sum F=0$ and $\sum M=0$ to determine the forces on both supports.

Hope this helps.